# ReactJS переходы по ссылкам (замена контента)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Доброго времени суток!
Начал изучать **ReactJS**, и сразу же столкнулся с проблемкой
Например имеется сайт, скажем большой сайт с *backend'ом*, где куча разных ссылок, при переходе по ссылкам кардинально изменяется вид.
Что я имею виду, например сайт с фильмами, на главной странице выводится список фильмов, при клике на фильм (пропадает список) и появляется информация о фильме
Вот тут и вопрос, как такое делают в **ReactJS**?
Если бы я такое делал например с помощью **jQuery**, это выглядело бы примерно так

```js
$("#content").html("И тут html который получил с сервера");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">тут менюшка<div>
<div id="content">тут сам контент<div>
```

А вот как такое сделать на reactjs даже предположить не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть библиотека, которая называется `react-router`, она позволяет это делать. В ней есть компоненты типа `Router`, `Route`, `Link` и прочие, с их помощью можно сделать одностраничное приложение с навигацией на клиенте.

Т.е. в нем определенному маршруту соответствует определенный набор компонентов.

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App>
      <Route exact path="/" render={ () => (
        <Redirect to="/heroes" />
      ) } />
      <Route exact path="/heroes" component={ Heroes } />
      <Route exact path="/details/hero/:id" component={ EditHeroContainer } />
    </App>        
  </BrowserRouter>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если сайт реально большой, это получается нужно маршруты прописывать практически для каждой ссылки? А как быть например с форумом, или react не предназначен для подобного?

Comment: Не совсем понял, для создания ссылки там есть компонент Link. Есть вычисляемые маршруты, как например - /details/hero/:id, в id будет попадать определенный номер и на основании этого номера можно отображать разные темы форума например. Вообще маршрут может отвечать за какую-то небольшую часть интерфейса, а может отвечать за целую страницу. Предлагаю вам прочесть несколько статей про это, они мне помогли - http://prgssr.ru/development/pogruzhenie-v-react-router.html

Comment: Спасибо за ссылочку
И я совсем обнаглею, но все же спрошу. А у вас там нет полезных ссылок в целом на React, Redux и может на ReactCSSTransitionGroup

Comment: По-моему документация лучшее пособие. Вот могу ссылку дать на документацию по Redux в переводе - https://github.com/rajdee/redux-in-russian#Документация , ну и видео по Redux же, но на английском - https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux